# /sys/power/resume: No such file or directory

Tags: kernel, drivers

I see this log:

```
/sys/power/resume: No such file or directory
```

Is it related to any kernel config?

Comment: it seems, since kernel 5.9.x, have the same warning

Comment: Check kernel config related to SLEEP and HIBERNATE. it solved my issue

Comment: @zermok Could you please elaborate what should we check exactly and what values should it have? Thanks!